# Use of Content Moderator in Virtual assistant template throws error

Tags: botframework

Turned on the content moderator by adding this code:

```
Use(new ContentModeratorMiddleware(settings.ContentModerator.Key, contentModeratorSettings.Value.Region)); to the defaultAdapter.cs.
```

Getting this error:

```
at System.Text.Encoding.GetBytes(String s)
at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Solutions.Middleware.ContentModeratorMiddleware.OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext context, NextDelegate next, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.AutoSaveStateMiddleware.OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, NextDelegate next, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in d:\a\1\s\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Builder\AutoSaveStateMiddleware.cs:line 60
at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Solutions.Middleware.EventDebuggerMiddleware.OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, NextDelegate next, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Solutions.Middleware.SetLocaleMiddleware.OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext context, NextDelegate next, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.ShowTypingMiddleware.OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, NextDelegate next, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in d:\a\1\s\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Builder\ShowTypingMiddleware.cs:line 71"
```

This happens before the trigger:

```
protected override async Task OnEventAsync(DialogContext dc, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
```

Comment: Sorry, this one fell by the wayside. I am not receiving this error. Can you include the error message (you only included the stack trace--need the actual error)? Can you try with a new VA bot? They [added a PR 3 days ago](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-solutions/pull/2505) that *might* have fixed this. Can you also include steps to reproduce the error?

Comment: I saw Darren providing the fix, I don't see the latest Nuget package with the fix yet

Comment: We should be releasing the 4.6 packages soon (which should include that fix). If you want it sooner, you can use [the MyGet feeds](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/master/UsingMyGet.md)

Comment: Let me know if you test the MyGet package (or wait for the 4.6) and how it goes.

Comment: I am going to wait for 4.6 package